# python: How to forward an instance's method call to its attribute

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
class Number(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Number, self).__init__()
        self.data = 10

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        def _missing(*args, **kwargs):
            method = getattr(self.data, name)
            return method(args[0])

        return _missing

a = Number()
b = Number()

print a.__add__(10)   # this is ok!
print a + 10          # TypeError: "unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Number' and 'int'"
print a + b           # TypeError: "unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Number' and 'Number'"
```

Question:
    What's the difference between "a.__add__(10)" and "a + 10", How can I hook the operator "+" ?

Comment: Override the `__add__` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python will only use an actual `__add__` method, not one that only "exists" due to `__getattr__`.

When adding `__add__ = (10).__add__` it works fine.

So what you'll want to do is adding proxy methods:

```
def __add__(self, *args): return self.data.__add__(*args)
def __sub__(self, *args): return self.data.__sub__(*args)
# ...
```

Comment: thank you for reply, but I want to use a more "dynamically" way to implement this, any suggestion? a python's built in number class has large amount of \__xx\__ methods, I don't want to add them one by one. :)

Comment: Well unfortunately that's the way to go - but you can do pretty much copy&paste, e.g. from [werkzeug's LocalProxy class](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/local.py#L350) which should work with minor changes that can be done with a search&replace operation.

Comment: @chinloon in https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2015-December/037348.html is interesting idea probably usefull for you...

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, but it's not beautiful:

```
import numbers

def redirect(name):
    def redirected(self, *args):
        assert len(args) <= 1
        if len(args) == 1 and isinstance(args[0], Number):
            return getattr(self._data, name)(args[0]._data)
        else:
            return getattr(self._data, name)(*args)
    return redirected

names = set(['__gt__', '__ge__'])
names.update(numbers.Real.__abstractmethods__)
methods = dict((name, redirect(name)) for name in names)
methods.update(
    {'__init__': lambda self, data: setattr(self, '_data', float(data))})
Number = type("Number", (), methods)
```

You can use it like this:

```
>>> a = Number(5)
>>> b = Number(7)
>>> a + 10
15.0
>>> a + b
12.0
>>> a > b
False
>>> a == Number(5.0)
True
```

Note that the type returned from the arithmetic operators is `float` and not `Number` (which may or may not be what you expected).

If you want to have integers, you can remove the `float()` call and change `numbers.Real` to `numbers.Integral`.
Note, however, that the arithmetic operators will cease to work with float values.